# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 hyperlink value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssrs-2008, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS 2005 and am running a  report, where an ID is displayed for each entry. Is it possible to hyperlink each ID to the same exact page, however passing the value of the ID in the url? For example..

The user clicks ID 1, and brings them to something like:
http://mywebpage.com/index.pl?ID=1

Same Web page, but the end would be ID=2,etc..

Is this possible? And if so, how? I don't know what to Google for this Haha.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to: Right click in the id field, go to properties, select "Action", click the radio button "Go to URL" - click in the expression and type ="http://mywebpage.com/index.pl?ID=" & Fields!ID.Value